# Seat Assignment on Via Rail's The Ocean

Tags: trains, canada, seating

I just booked a ticket from Halifax to Montréal and got seat 7C assigned. I do know that this train ran with a 2+1 seat setting in their Economy wagons in the past. So I am wondering if I would have a single seat. Unfortunately I cannot find any diagram [here](https://corpo.viarail.ca/en/projects-infrastructure/train-fleet/renaissance-coach-car) or [here](https://www.viarail.ca/en/explore-our-destinations/trains/atlantic-canada/montreal-halifax-ocean/traincars).

Did anyone ride this train recently and knows if 7C is a single seat? Is it AB + C or A + BC?

Comment: The picture on [Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/montreal-to-halifax-by-train.htm) shows a 2+1 configuration, so AB + C seems likely.  I suppose it's possible, though, that seat A is on the right-hand side of the train, or that there are other cars with the opposite configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not a single seat. I asked Via Rail through their Twitter account, it seems that they also have wagons with 2+2 settings on this route.

See also:

- https://twitter.com/VIA_Rail/status/1153777441342730240
- https://corpo.viarail.ca/fr/projets-infrastructure/parc-ferroviaire/voiture-coach-lrc/schema

Answer (score 6):

It's annoying to find, but there's a link to [Seat Numbering](https://reservia.viarail.ca/help/helptopic.aspx?t=Seat_numbering_LRC_HEP) on the sidebar when booking a ticket.  Unfortunately it doesn't appear to match up with your seat number.

> As to the Renaissance cars, there are 16 rows in both classes.
>   Seats A are window seats, B are aisle seats and S are single seats.

The French language site also has a [diagram](https://corpo.viarail.ca/fr/projets-infrastructure/parc-ferroviaire/voiture-club-renaissance/schema) suggesting that the seat numbering system is AB+S.

[image]

From this I'd speculate that your "C" seat is equivalent to the single "S" seat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately it's not a single seat. See my answer.